# Microcontroller GPIO ports referred to as Parallel Ports

Tags: microcontroller

A coworker of mine, quite frequently, refers to the GPIO ports of say an 8051, AVR, or any microcontroller as "parallel ports". Is this a common nomenclature in industry? I find it kind of confusing, I always just referred to it as the GPIO port.

Comment: Well I don't refer them even as a "port" because a port for me is a group of signals with a common purpose, like a memory port which includes address, data and control. For me the GPIOs are just a bunch of I/O. So you see, your way of calling them is also confusing (to me) :)

Comment: @claudio as far as I know, most major semiconductor companies group GPIO in 8 bit/pin ports as far as memory access and physical grouping goes, and use the word ***port*** extensively. TI msp430 port 1, 2, etc. ATMEL port A, B, etc.

Comment: While odd, it's not a unrealistic description of how a GPIO port can work.

Comment: "Parallel port" is the term for the printer port on Windows PCs and predecessors until about 2001.  Probably 99% of non-Apple printers had a parallel port.  It used 8 data lines and a handful of control lines, and a GPIO was a common way to drive it.  Even if it's not driving a printer, it's correct to call it parallel if multiple bits of data go to the same place, e.g. 3 wires setting a LED light level 0-7.   It made for expensive ports and thick cables, hence the push in computing to switch to serial (i.e. RS232, RS422, U**S**B, FireWire, **S**ATA).

Comment: yes, datasheets from various chip vendors use this term.  in the pc it was also a chip with parallel gpio that was connected to the external port.  The gpio pins are accessed in parallel in many of these implementations, so there is nothing wrong with this term, it is not some dated old fasioned thing it is correct.  likewise GPIO is a term not used by every chip vendor, so using that term is at the same time correct and incorrect from one chip to another if the chip vendor is the authority on that product (which essentially they are since this is arbitrary).  some say dio instead of gpio.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Microcontrollers typically have several groups of GPIO pins, labeled PORTA, PORTB, PORTC etc. or something similar (perhaps P0, P1, etc.).

Each of these ports is referred to as a parallel I/O port in the manufacturers' datasheets, **because all pins of the port can be acted upon in parallel by one machine instruction**.  The width of the port dictated by the data path width of the microcontroller (8, 16, or 32-bits).

[image]

```
               (taken from the datasheet for the PIC32MX795F512L)
```

So the pins on the first port of an 8-bit µC might be referred to as RA0 through RA7, and on a 32-bit µC, they would be referred to as pins RA0 through RA31 (where in this example R stands for Register, the next letter is the port name, followed by the bit number -- other microcontrollers may have different naming conventions, such as P0.0 through P0.7 etc.).

Typically each port will have at least three registers associated with it (sometimes more); one to set the direction of the pins to either input or output, another to read the current input state of the digital pins, and another to set the output state of the pins. There may be another to specify whether each pin is open-drain or push-pull output.

Virtually all microcontrollers will be able to read or write to each of these registers all at once; they may or may not have the ability to read individual bits, or to write individual bits of a register without affecting the others in the port, depending on the instruction set of the processor.

Even if a processor does not have an instruction to read or write an individual bit, I/O libraries may hide this from the user; for example the Arduino digital I/O library has a function called digitalWrite(pin, value) which is implemented on a variety of different microcontrollers, not all of which may have an instruction to write to just one bit.  In which case, it would need to either to a read-modify-write of the output register, or keep a *shadow register* in memory to remember the last state of the output port, so when updating just one bit, it could mask in the new status without affecting the other pins.  Likewise, Arduinos have functions to read a digital pin, and set a pin to input or output mode.

The Arduino I/O library only allows digital pins to be written individually, since the ports used will vary from one board to another and the pins may not even be assigned consecutively.  So instead, the functions just use an abstract digital pin number (0-13).  So for an Arduino, the concept of a "parallel port" doesn't really exist, which is where some of the confusion may come from.  But under its layer of abstraction, they are still there on the embedded microcontroller.

The actual port pins on the processor can be quite different from one processor to another, for example, here are the assignments for the Arduino Uno (8-bit ATmega 328P) and Arduino DUE (32-bit ARM SAM3X8E):

```
Pin #    Uno    DUE

0        PD0    A.8
1        PD1    A.9
2        PD2    B.25
3        PD3    C.28
4        PD4    C.26/A.29
5        PD5    C.25
6        PD6    C.24
7        PD7    C.23
8        PB0    C.22
9        PB1    C.21
10       PB2    C.29/A.28
11       PB3    D.7
12       PB4    D.8
13       PB5    B.27
```

So while the assignments for the Uno are straightforward (using all of Port D first, then six bits of Port B), the port assignments for the DUE are all over the place.  Two of the digital pins (4 and 10) are even connected to more than one port pin of the ARM.

Finally, there may be another set of registers on a microcontroller that allow some of the port pins to be used as analog inputs.  Any pins so designated will always be addressed individually; you cannot read a group of analog pins in parallel.  And for almost all microcontrollers, peripherals such as UARTs, I²C, SPI, etc. usually share pins with the parallel ports; when these peripherals are enabled, the pins are taken over by the peripheral and are no longer available from the parallel port registers.

Comment: I have often implemented the WriteBit(Port, Bit) type function as a read-modify-write cycle when the specific bit instruction is not available (and in a lot of older controllers, that was the underlying mechanism anyway).

Comment: @PeterSmith Thx, added that to my answer.

Answer (score 6):

This sort of thing will vary from person to person, based on experience, what literature they've read, and who they've worked with.  Because all the bits of a port can be read or written with a single machine instruction, it is essentially a parallel port.  And it could be contrasted with a serial port, since many microcontrollers have those built in, and there will be an associated I/O pin that works independently of the others.

Comment: And maybe in the past, he used an LPT port (aka "parallel port") on a PC as poor-man's GPIOs and this stuck in his mind.

Answer (score 1):

A GPIO *pin* is a general purpose input/output *pin*. This means that it can be programmed to be an input or an output and, in the latter case, it even can be programmed further:

- Open drain
- 3-state
- Drive strength
- Output levels

Because of this, it is not unusual that two consecutive pins in a group of (usually 8) pins are programmed in a different way. In this case, it may even not make much sense to refer to the whole group as a *port*.

The term *parallel port* originated from the port where printers were connected to. In the context of microcontrollers, it may make sense to refer to a group of pins as a *parallel port* if they are read or written in parallel, but not in general. For instance, certain GPIO pins of an 8-bit port may indeed represent a serial port. So, it would make not much sense talking of the serial pins in parallel port x.